# Adoption requirements for the survey running on AirConsole

Tags: airconsole

I really like the capability of walking up to any web browser and being able to complete a survey using AirConsole app on my smartphone. I have a few questions regarding usage.

1. Do I build a "game" in order to feed the survey questions?  I would like to have a call to an API that allows me to control the questions per user and store their responses.
2. Does the smartphone user have to be on the same network or could this be done with any web browser and smart phone as long as they are both on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you build a game. You would also have to run your own server to serve and store the answers.
2. It could be done with any web browser that is connected to the internet.